# Opening New Programs using Commands in Mac OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, command

I want to open programs in Terminal by writing a single command, like what is already done for Java complilation:

`javac HelloWorld.java`

For any program I install, that functionality isn't available. For example, to open SWI-Prolog I have to type

`/opt/local/bin/swipl`

when I want to type just

`swipl`

which results in a `-bash: swipl: command not found`. How do I create this new command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust the BASH PATH environment variable. Edit your `.bash_login` or `.bash_profile` in your home directory, add at the end of the file the follwing lines:

```
 PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin
 export PATH
```

Source your file or simply close the current terminal and open a new one.